Finding the roots of $P_1-P_2$, given those of $P_1+P_2$
Given two polynomials $P_1(x)$ and $P_2(x)$ and the roots of the polynomial $Q_1(x) = P_1(x)+P_2(x)$, which are al real. I would like to find the roots of the polynomial $Q_2(x) = P_1(x)-P_2(x)$, which I assume will also be real.
My strategy was given a root $r$ of $Q_1(x)$ I can try to deform $Q_1(x)$ into $Q_2(x)$ and track how the root changes. For this a constructed the function $H(x,t) = P_1(x)+tP_2(x) = 0$. Differentiating gives:
$$ \frac{\partial H(x,t)}{\partial t} = (P_1'(x)+tP'_2(x))\frac{dx}{dt}+P_2(x)=0.$$
Hence we find the differential equation:
$$ \frac{dx}{dt} = -\frac{P_2(x)}{P_1'(x)+P_2'(x)t}.$$
Which I don't know how to solve (and probably has not some nice solution). Is there any other way to determine the solutions of $Q_2(x)$ from the solutions of $Q_1(x)$? Optimally I would like an analytical solution, but I am also satisied with a numerical solution that is easier (complexity wise) than just solving $Q_2(x)$ numerically.

Yes you are right, I made an edit.

This method seems likely to fail when a real root becomes imaginary, as the root curves are often non-differentiable there.

Actually I am assuming that both $Q_1(x)$ and $Q_2(x)$ only have real roots. Not sure if it guarantees that along the path the roots stay real, but nevertheless I will add it in the question.

Easier to write as $t=-P_1/P_2$ to get $dx/dt$ and integrate separably, though it seems like running around in circles as you already know $H(x,t)=0$ is the answer. Why don't you try an example with your conditions and see for yourself?

You can't infer the roots of the difference $Q_2(x) = P_1(x)-P_2(x)$ of two polynomials from the roots of their sum $Q_1(x) = P_1(x)+P_2(x)$ for the reason that the sum can be written $(P_1(x)+P_3(x))+(P_2(x)-P_3(x))$ where $P_3(x)$ is an arbitrary polynomial : in this case, the difference becomes : $(P_1(x)-P_2(x))+2 P_3(x)$ which has evidently in general other roots than $(P_1(x)-P_2(x))$ ... all this being possible with real roots only.
An example : take $P_1(x)=x^2,P_2(x)=4x,P_3(x)=2$ ;
we haven't the same roots for $(P_1(x)-P_2(x))=x^2-4x$ (which are $x=0$ and $x=4$) and $(P_1(x)-P_2(x))+2 P_3(x)=x^2-4x+4$ which is the double root $x=2$

I see, I understand the argument if you only know $Q_1(x)$ but it seems to me that if you explicitly know $P_1(x)$ and $P_2(x)$ (Which I do) it gives you more information? But maybe this is a false intuition.

See the example I just added.
